# How to get MD5 original message if partial message is known?

Tags: hash, cryptography

Suppose I have `m1` and `md5(m1+m2)`. How do I recover `m2`?

Comment: Only by guessing `m2`. If `m2` is sufficiently easy to guess (e.g. a typical password), it's possible to recover it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Secure hashes, by design, cannot be reversed. Quite apart from which, there are fewer MD5 hashes (2^128) than there are possible values for `m2` (effectively infinite), so it's impossible for there to be a single unique correct answer anyway.

Comment: I've always found that beautiful about hash functions. There is an infinite number of collisions, but we can't find a single one…

Answer (score 6):

Nick's answer is correct.

I just want to point out that if you know the length of m2 and if is not too long, you could in principle try all possible values of m2 until you find a match with md5(m1+m2). For example if m1 is the salt of a password and m2 is the actual password what I just outlined is indeed possible. In most cases the length of m2 would be 8-12 characters. If you restrict yourself to characters you can enter from a standard keyboard, the above is very possible and is indeed used to crack passwords.